# Can i access API out side the network if i am using windows service hosting

Tags: owin

I have hosted Web API using owing self hosting on production(http://localhost:8181/api/values) but i am not able to access on my machine with url(http://170.xx.xx.xx:8181/api/values).

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

when you start your Selfhosted Web API, you register the url on which Web API is listening:

```
//string baseUrl = "http://localhost:" + 8181;  // reachable only on localhost                         
string baseUrl = "http://170.xx.xx.xx:" + 8181; 

WebApp.Start<WebService.Startup>(baseUrl);
```

Therefore make sure baseUrl contains the address under which your Web API should be reachable.